# PHP login in if/else conditional not executing else condition

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a small script that takes a username and password from my client and if their credentials are correct they are taken to their site directory on my development server.

The `if` condition works perfectly and responds to correct credentials that match their counter parts in my MySQL database.

However, the `else` condition will not execute at all (i.e. it won't direct the user to the error page if their credentials are incorret). I think the `while` loop may be tripping up the logic but I need the `$row` variable to get the directory field from the DB.

Any ideas?

```
$username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

$pass = md5($password);

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "digital_server");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$pass'";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    if($query) {
        header("Location: " . $row['directory'] . "/");
    } 

    else {
        header("Location: http://dev.myserver.com/error.php");
    }
}
```

**RESOLVED** 
Perfect thanks to all who helped.

**Amended code block** 
Removed the while and created a `$row` variable to get the data I need for the `if` logic

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        header("Location: " . $row['directory'] . "/");
    } 

    else {
        header("Location: http://dev.myserver.com/error.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// No need of while here
//while() {     
    if( mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 ) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        header("Location: " . $row['directory'] . "/");
    } else {
        header("Location: http://dev.myserver.com/error.php");
    }
```

**Option 2**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$pass'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

   if(count($row ) > 0 ) {
            header("Location: " . $row['directory'] . "/");
        } else {
            header("Location: http://dev.myserver.com/error.php");
        }
```

Comment: How can I use the `$row` variable if I don't create it in the `while` loop?

Comment: Yep just figured that out as well. Removed the `while` and just created a `$row` variable. Thanks.

Comment: Will accept as correct answer when time allows it =]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`mysqli_num_rows($result);`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if( mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 ) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  header("Location: " . $row['directory'] . "/");
}else{
  header("Location: http://dev.myserver.com/error.php");
}
```

You can always catch the error in the query using 
 [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
        $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

        $pass = md5($password);

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "digital_server");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$pass'";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

       if( mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 ) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
      header("Location: " . $row['directory'] . "/");
    }
else
{
      header("Location: http://dev.myserver.com/error.php");
    }
```